# How to prepare an array for an LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

The input array has 4 columns: the first 3 are real numbers between -1 and 1 and the 4th is the desired output that can be either -1 or 0 or +1 (this is a classification problem, -1 and 1 represent useful categories and 0 means the sample doesn't fall to any of them). Obviously the network type is chosen to be LSTM because the category depends not only on the values of the first 3 columns but also  on the properties of the preceding samples.

With a simple non-LSTM network I would do (but I'm not sure even this is correct as I'm totally new to Keras and using Python for neural networks, I've only used Encog in Java and C# before and it didn't have LSTMs)

```
# dataset = the array I've described above
x = dataset[:, 0:3]
y = dataset[:, 3]
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=10)
```

But with an LSTM this raises ValueError as an LSTM requires a 3D input array and I don't understand how to reshape the array I've described correctly.

Comment: You need to extract (overlapped) data-chunks from your data and then feed those to LSTM layer.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Keras and have access to a GPU I'd recommend using a `CuDNNLSTM` instead of a regular LSTM for faster training. Back to your question though.

The LSTM requires a 3D input so here's a quick example to get you started. Let's say you have the following two columns of tabular data:

```
series 1: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0
series 2: 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1
```

So the data is present as follows (10, 2):

```
from numpy import array
data = array([
    [0.1, 1.0],
    [0.2, 0.9],
    [0.3, 0.8],
    [0.4, 0.7],
    [0.5, 0.6],
    [0.6, 0.5],
    [0.7, 0.4],
    [0.8, 0.3],
    [0.9, 0.2],
    [1.0, 0.1]])
```

In order to reshape this to a 3D input, you'd do the following:

```
data = data.reshape(1, 10, 2)
```

where you're reshaping the data into a 1 sample of 10 time steps and 2 features.

Source:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/

If you need a more direct answer let me know.

Comment: Thanks. What if my training dataset is 1000-records-long? Should I reshape it as data.reshape(100, 10, 2)? Also how should I reshape the correct responses array then? I don't seek to predict any of the inputs but to categorize, e.g. [0.8, 0.3] should yield 1 if going after [0.7, 0.4], [0.9, 0.2] should yield -1 if going after [0.8, 0.3]  and [1.0, 0.1] should yield 0 if going after [0.9, 0.2].

Comment: It says ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 100 input samples and 1000 target samples.

Comment: And what if I want overlapping samples? E.g. given this dataset I would want [0.1, 1.0], [0.2, 0.9], [0.3, 0.8], then [0.2, 0.9], [0.3, 0.8], [0.4, 0.7], then [0.3, 0.8], [0.4, 0.7], [0.5, 0.6], then [0.4, 0.7], [0.5, 0.6], [0.6, 0.5], etc - for every single element of the input data set (except the first ones) I'd like itself + some previous.